# SQL Query - Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this error but i can't manage to find out the error.

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, password, email, pais, cidade, data_registo, tipo_conta, estado_conta, creditos) 
values (admin, 6910b64010c9660ad77d9bb7adb43e75, admin@iol.pt, just4, test, now(), '1', '2', '5')
```

***It says:*** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@xd.vbudfg, ugwfghuifweui, ugwefg, now(), '1', '2', '5')' at line 1

Comment: You have to enclose string values in single quotes. You don't have to enclose numeric values in single quotes. You are doing just the opposite.

Comment: @bfavaretto: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JimGarrison, okay, made it an answer. Should I delete the comment?

Comment: @xRed: instead of adding `[solved]` to the title, click the little green checkmark next to the answer which you feel solves your issue. Also, the correct spelling of `Querie` is `Query`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing quotes round many of your strings. For example, the email, `admin@iol.pt` should be `'admin@iol.pt'`.

Your query should read:

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, password, email, pais, cidade, data_registo, tipo_conta, estado_conta, creditos) values ('admin', '6910b64010c9660ad77d9bb7adb43e75', 'admin@iol.pt', 'just4', 'test', now(), '1', '2', '5')
```

*Note that if the last three values have a numerical data-type, you won't need quotes*.

Answer (score 10):

Quote your values

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, password, email, pais, cidade, data_registo, tipo_conta, estado_conta, creditos) values ('admin', '6910b64010c9660ad77d9bb7adb43e75', 'admin@iol.pt', 'just4', 'test', now(), '1', '2', '5')
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to enclose string values in single quotes. You don't have to enclose numeric values in single quotes. You are doing just the opposite.

So, your query should be (assuming `tipo_conta`, `estado_conta` and `creditos` are `INT` columns):

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores (username, password, email, pais, cidade, data_registo, tipo_conta, estado_conta, creditos) 
VALUES ('admin', '6910b64010c9660ad77d9bb7adb43e75', 'admin@iol.pt', 'just4', 'test', now(), 1, 2, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO utilizadores 
    (
        username, password, email, pais, 
        cidade, data_registo, tipo_conta, 
        estado_conta, creditos
    ) 
values 
    (
        'admin', '6910b64010c9660ad77d9bb7adb43e75', 'admin@iol.pt', 'just4', 
        'test', now(), '1', 
        '2', '5'
    );
```

You can't ignore a single `quote(')` for a `varchar` datatype. . .